# segregating wildfly subsystem configurations into a separate xml file

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I have seen that jboss 10 (aka wildfly) provides a standalone.xml file to configure different extensions (e.g. logging, ejb, jpa etc.) and corresponding subsystems supported by the application server. This xml file grows > 1000 lines when we try to add more extensions and subsystems into it. This reduces the readability of the file.

Is there any way to segregate the subsystem configurations into separate xml files and link those to standalone.xml?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to use kind of include or import for some parts.

As it is split into 'main' sections like the profile, management interfaces and socket-binding the structure is better readable.
In general I use the power of CLI or management console to administrate the configuration.

Comment: The important thing is to have a CLI script that is readable. Don't worry about the standalone.xml file because that is for machine consumption.

Answer (score 0):

In case what you want to configure is the WAR/EJB modules that you are deploying, they may be configured in a specific `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file inside the EAR itself: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly

It offers quite some flexibility to enhance behavior of your deployment.